# is possible to share VM or groups of VM with several services in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm working with a project that will use Microservice architecture, I'm using App Engine, each service of my project is deployed as a service in App Engine, each service in App Engine uses one or more VM Machine.

I'm using the `App Engine Flexible Environment` because I use `nodejs` and `Python 3.4`

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

I know I can limit the number of instance for each service using the follow settings for app.yaml

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 10
  cool_down_period_sec: 120 # default value
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5

resources:
  cpu: .1
  memory_gb: 0.18
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

I know there is `Standard Environment` that we have some **free quota** and will be charged after the app consumes more than of the **free quota**, this is really useful and is what I need but I can't use `Nodejs` and `Python3.4` with that environment.

Can I set which VM or group of VM the apps will use? my goal is try to save money about the instances because maybe we will have several services, it can be expensive mainly at the beginning !

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the moment. Even if each app runs in a container it uses a separate virtual machine(which kinda makes no sense). You can't even define the containers of the same app to run on a specific VM or a specific group of VMs.

I'm confident that this will change in the future but based on the records this may take 1 - 2 more years or even more so don't hold your breath .

I assume you are already aware that flexible/managed VM environment require at least one instance to be always on and it's not covered by a free quota.

It's worth to note that Amazon Beanstalk [allows](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html) you run multiple containers on a single instance.

Comment: Azure App Service also allows for multiple apps per plan (where scaling and billing is controlled at the plan level).